# how to get output of dmidecode and fdisk commands as normal user?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to get system information and hard disk information using dmideode and fdisk as normal user in Centos 6.4. But i can't get it.Can anybody help me how to do this?.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a root access to your machine, you could configure `sudo` to allow specifics binaries for a specific user to be called without typing a password.

To do so:

1. Type: `sudo visudo`
2. Add the line: `user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/path/of/your/binary`

Then you'll be able to call your binary without typing a password:

```
sudo /path/of/your/binary
```

Comment: @Vicky: You're welcome. You could tick this answer if you find it useful.